# How to build ASP.NET MVC user controls into class libraries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, using

I'm trying to build some .ascx controls into a class library for plugins for a CMS I'm building.

My project type is a typical C# class libary with references added for system.web.mvc & friends.

My problem arises in trying to create a strongly-typed user control.  My control looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TagCloudWidget.Models.TagCloudWidgetData>" %>
```

Even though I have another public class in the same project under the namespace `TagCloudWidget.Models`, I can't seem to get the `.ascx` file to recognize this.  I've tried including `Imports` for the namespace, but then it just complains that the namespace doesn't exist.  The TagCloudData class file looks like this:

```
namespace TagCloudWidget.Models
{
public class TagCloudWidgetData
{
    public IList<TagCount> TagCounts { get; set; }
    public ContentTypes ContentType;
    public string Controller;
    public string Action;

    public TagCloudWidgetData(IList<TagCount> tagCounts, ContentTypes contentType, string controller, string action)
    {
        TagCounts = tagCounts;
        ContentType = contentType;
        Controller = controller;
        Action = action;
    }
}
}
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Since the suggestion below, I've tried adding a code-behind file.  I think I'm closer to figuring out what's wrong, but I'm still not able to find a solution.  In the project, I've added references to System.Web and System.Web.Mvc.  But, in the using section of the codebehind file, when I type "using System.", auto-complete doesn't even show System.Web or System.Web.Mvc as available options.  It's like they just don't exist on disc.  Other projects are able to include them and reference them just fine.  I suppose this is the source of my problem, so I'm hopeful once I figure this out the rest will just fall into place.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar problems with an application that I started with the beta release.  The only thing I've found that works is to create a code-behind file for the control and define the inheritance in the code-behind.  Then in the control, have it inherit from the class defined in your code-behind.  In newer projects, built from scratch using 1.0, I don't have this problem -- but then again I don't have my partial classes defined in a library, either.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  This is a new project built from scratch with 1.0, so maybe we're still missing some small piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Success!  Somehow, my .ascx file had been marked "content" in the file properties instead of "compile".  Once I fixed that, I can now reference the necessary assemblies and load/run the plugin without problems.  Thanks for the tip on the codebehind file!

(update) The other tip I figured out last night is that my plugin also has to be in the app's /bin directory as well as my /widgets directory, otherwise I get a "Could not load type..." exception.  I haven't figured out yet how to wire up ASP.NET MVC so I only have to have it in 1 place, but when I do, I'll post back here.